# cursor.execute in python for SQL

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I need the script to monitor the sql server expiration from linux by python code and

In SQL output is coming but in linux, it gives the following error:

```
>>> cursor.execute("select loginproperty('tibbr_db','DaysUntilExpiration')")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('ODBC data type -150 is not supported.  Cannot read column .', 'HY000')
```

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly cast the [LOGINPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx) return value to an integer to work around the data type mapping problem by changing the query from this:

```
"select loginproperty('tibbr_db','DaysUntilExpiration')"
```

to this:

```
"select cast(loginproperty('tibbr_db','DaysUntilExpiration') as integer)"
```

The `DaysUntilExpiration` property in SQL Server should always return an integer, so you won't see any type errors with the explicit conversion.

ODBC type `-150` looks like a SQL Server [variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) type, which pyodbc doesn't map to a python type.

Comment: @user3311501 it is polite to mark this as the correct answer if indeed it fixed the problem.  :)

Comment: If you're using FreeTDS, I'd recommend having a look at this driver instead if you're using SQL Server; it is much more feature complete and performant: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36437